# print screen > ckeditor > CakePHP CakeEmail

Tags: php, image, email, cakephp, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor 3.6.5 (revision 7647) field (on a CakePHP 2.2.1 site) where users paste print screen images (only works on Firefox). The html generated by the paste (button paste from word) is something like this:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

At a certain point I have to send by Email the html on these fields which should include the images.

Reading [base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures][1] and [how-to-embed-images-in-email][2] I figured that the Email should have an attachment with the image.

My question is how can I transform the src of the image on a file? This way I intend to transform the HTML before send.

I have tried with success to attach a file with:

```
$data = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');//file_get_contents('http://' . env('HTTP_HOST') . $fileInfo['url'] . '/disable-auth-key:' . Configure::read('Security.salt') . '.' . $fileInfo['ext']);
$handle = fopen(TMP . 'print_screen.png', 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);

$email = new CakeEmail(array(
    'log' => true,
    'config' => 'smtp',
    'returnPath' => 'return@mydomain.pt',
    'from' => array('app@mydomain.pt' => 'APP'),
    'to'  => array('name@domain.pt' => 'Name'),
    'emailFormat' => 'html',
    'subject' => 'image test',
    'domain' => '@uab.pt',
    'attachments' => array(
        'print_screen.png' => array(
            'file' => TMP . 'print_screen.png',
            'mimetype' => 'image/png',
            'contentId' => 'Print-Screen-01'
        )
    )
));

$email->send('test|<img src="cid:print_screen.png@Print-Screen-01">|');
```

On GMail I have access to the attachment file but on the body no image. Where is the source

```
<div id=":85x">test|<img>|</div>
```

On Outlook, no attachments and the source is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">test|<img src="cid:print_screen.png@Print-Screen-01">
```

I'm also open to other solutions that achieve the same result.

Comment: You can create the image in the webroot, and just post a link of the image in the email

Comment: @noslone thank you: the images shouldn't be public, in my case (requirement that was missing on my question); this solution also works but in many mail clients readers will have to authorize the download of the files (at least one first time) to see them; has the advantage of sending smaller Emails if that is an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the src attribute of the image tag the cid value should be  I was using @.

The correct line of code

```
$email->send('test|<img src="cid:Print-Screen-01">|');
```